# Microsoft Access 'File not Found' error on opening front-end database

Tags: vba, ms-access, file-not-found

Opening a Microsoft Access front-end database randomly started popping up 'File not Found' for all users - but not me (I'm the developer).

Turns out I was not using the Autoexec Macro to launch the opening form called Startup. I had just put the form name into the 'Current Database' option 'Display Form:'.

That worked for a very long time, and then it didn't.

I just added a macro called Autoexec which does one thing: opens the Startup form.

The 'File not Found' warning has gone away.

Resolved own issue based on research and a lucky guess.